# How to put where condition and join in cursor Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi i want to put a where condition and join tables in my query but i can't find any example

as for now i'm using this code, but i don't know where to put the join and where condition

```
 public Cursor getUsers() {
    Cursor localCursor =
            this.myDataBase.query(TBL_INFO, new String[] {
                            KEY_ID,
                            KEY_NAME},
                    null,
                    null, null, null, null);

    if (localCursor != null)
        localCursor.moveToFirst();
    return localCursor;
}
```

I'm wondering what's with the null value? is there any syntax that i can follow? thank you for the help!

Comment: I'd use a `rawQuery`, and make my life easier. A lot easier.

Comment: I recommend Der Golem hint, use rawQuery

Comment: can i have a sample code for it?

Comment: and also do i need to put it on my DBHepler or should i put in on my activity?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.query(tableName, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

You need to put your where condition in the selection part

Eg:

```
String selection="columnA=123";
```

For join you could try something like, tableName can be given `tableName="table1,table2";`
then your selection can have the conditions.(Have not tried this just theoritical)

Comment: how can i put a selection where my where condition is getting the value from another query? do i need to put table1.columnA = table2.columnA?

Comment: If things get too complicated you could always move to a raw query